# Scrapy: extract text from span without class or id

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I have the following html structure:

[image: html structure]

I would like to extract the text ("“Business-Thinking”-Fokus im Master-Kurs") from the span highlighted (using Scrapy), however I have trouble reaching to it as it does not contain any specific class or id.

I tried to access it with the following absolute xPath:

```
sel.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/h1/span/text()').extract()
```

I don't get any error, however it returns a blank file, meaning the text is not extracted.

**Note**: The parent classes are not unique, that's why I'm not using a relative path. As the text varies, I also cannot reach the span by looking for the text it contains.

Do you have any suggestion on how I should modify my xPath to extract the text? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alex, could you share the html structure as a code and not a link to the image.
It would also help to have the link to the webpage that you wish to extract so that we can test against it.

Comment: Hi Ryan, here is the link to the webpage: https://aback-blog.iwi.unisg.ch/2021/02/18/business-thinking-fokus-im-master-kurs/
What I'm trying to do is extract the title of each blog article. I'm not sure how to share just an extract of the html code showing the whole structure but without pasting the whole detailed code as it would be unreadable.

Comment: It looks to me the parent classes are unique. For example "container-blogsingle" only appears once in the several pages I looked at. Another anchor point is the title always precedes a div with the class "row page-header". It's also always a h1 tag after a div with the class "container". There are many options here.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mr_mooo_cow, I used the class "container-blogsingle" as an anchor point and I could extract the title. It remains a mystery to me why it didn't work with the absolute xPath... but the case is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load the page using `scrapy shell url` it loads without javascript.
When you look at source without javascript, the xpath to the span is `/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div/h1/span`

To load webpages with javascript in Scrapy use Splash.

Comment: This xpath indeed works! May I ask how exactly you load the page without javascript? I ran ```scrap shell url``` and then ```view(response)```, but the source code of the page looks the same as the original when I inspect it... Did I miss any step? Sorry I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: You can `print(response.text)` in the shell or when using `view(response)`, go to dev tools, Network tab, make sure Disable cache is checked, click ctrl+shift+P in the filter box, start typing Javascript and choose disable Javascript. Reload the page and the source will be the source for the page loaded without Javascript. I'm new myself, just learned it this week ;)